# Carousel page does not swipe on some device

Tags: xaml, win-universal-app, carousel, xamarin.forms, win-phone-silverlight-8.1

I've created a Xamarin Forms project. I have the following XAML in my project:

```
 <CarouselPage>
  <ContentPage>
    <StackLayout>
      <Label Text="Red" />
      <BoxView Color="Red" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
    </StackLayout>
  </ContentPage>
  <ContentPage>
    <StackLayout>
      <Label Text="Green" />
      <BoxView Color="Green" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
    </StackLayout>
  </ContentPage>
  <ContentPage>
    <StackLayout>
      <Label Text="Blue" />
      <BoxView Color="Blue" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
    </StackLayout>
  </ContentPage>
</CarouselPage>
```

Now the Carousel page works on the following platforms:

- UWP - localMachine
- Windows 8.1 - localMachine
- Android - emulator

It does not work for the following platforms:

- UWP - device (mobile)
- WinPhone (WinPhone 8.1) - device (mobile)

It does not recognize the swipe gesture on the phones. How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what was causing this issue, but I created a new project and shifted all my existing code to that project which then fixed the carousel page. Now working!